# Newtosoft, PCL & Xamarin.Droid

Tags: c#, json, json.net, xamarin.android

I'am facing to a strange problem.

I have a generic code that's was in my PCL project.
This code is currently perferctly working in my windows phone project, but not in the android one.

Here the code : ( the method that have the problem is CreateListFriend )

```
public class Friend : IFriend<User>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        private static volatile Friend instance;
        private static object syncRoot = new Object();

        private Friend() { }

        public static Friend Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    lock (syncRoot)
                    {
                        if (instance == null)
                            instance = new Friend();
                    }
                }

                return instance;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Populate friend instance
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="json">Json friend string</param>
        public void PopulateFriend(string json)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
            {
                var resultObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Friend>(json);
                Friend.Instance.Id = resultObj.Id;
                Friend.Instance.UserId = resultObj.UserId;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create friend list from json
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="json">json string</param>
        /// <returns>friend list</returns>
        public List<Friend> CreateListFriend(string json)
        {
            List<Friend> resultObj = new List<Friend>();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
            {
                resultObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Friend>>(json);
            }

            return resultObj;

        }
    }
```

[image]

As you can see in the previous picture, Json.net is able to "deserialize" but the object friend donc have the correct "fields"....

I already tried to supress the class and recreate it...
I already created a structure with the same fields, and all json deserialize it correctly, but i don't want to do it by this way.

Is somebody have an idea...

Comment: Why is the `Friend` class a singleton? A list of singleton does not make any sense for me because singleton means that you want to have only a single instance of `Friend`. Could you please clarify why it is needed? Additionally - as far as a I know - the `JsonConvert` needs a public constructor and you defined it as private. But if it works with private constructor then the problem may be that you use singleton and all the list items will be the last deserialized instance.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, the singleton in friend was an architecture mistake that i not change.  I delete the friend singleton but now i have this error "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for type Cheer_up_app.Model.Friend. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path '[0].User', line 1, position 9."

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume we have two `JSON` source file:

**friend.json:**

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "userId": 6
}
```

**friends.json:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "userId": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "userId": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "userId": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "userId": 5
    }
]
```

We also have the `Friend` class. Based on your example your class is a POCO for Entity Framework. `JsonProperty` attribute is not needed if the source file has the same property names as your class.

**Note:** I did not define any constructor for `Friend` class so it will have only one public parameterless constructor by default.

```cs
public class Friend
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("userId")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("User: Id={0}; UserId={1}", Id, UserId);
    }
}
```

I would separate the logic for creating `Friend` instances. Just for an example I create a `FriendLoader` class.

```
public class FriendLoader
{
    public Friend LoadFriend(string jsonSource)
    {
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonSource) ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Friend>(jsonSource);
    }

    public List<Friend> LoadFriends(string jsonSource)
    {
        var friends = new List<Friend>();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonSource))
        {
            friends = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Friend>>(jsonSource);
        }

        return friends;
    }
}
```

Here is the console app to test the above code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string friendJson = File.ReadAllText("friend.json");
        string friendsJson = File.ReadAllText("friends.json");

        var loader = new FriendLoader();

        var friend = loader.LoadFriend(friendJson);
        var friends = loader.LoadFriends(friendsJson);

        Console.WriteLine("One friend:");
        Console.WriteLine(friend);

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("List of friends:");
        friends.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

By the way, could you please show the definition of your `IFriend<T>` interface?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the delay I did not have the time this week to post.

This is not related to my class but to the android.platform.

We just need to tell android platform to preserve all attribute with this :

```
[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
```

Thanks for your time :)